# Response from HttpURLConnection in JAVA yields garbage value

Tags: java

**Scenario:** I need to hit a HTTPS URL to fetch .csv file or it's contents. I can successfully get the desired contents using Advanced REST client plugin in Chrome browser. But get a garbage value while trying to do the same using the java code.

**Code:**

```
public class AnotherBean {
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36";

    public void printAnotherMessage() {
        System.out.println("I am called by Quartz jobBean using CronTriggerFactoryBean");

        AnotherBean anotherBean = new AnotherBean();

        try {
            System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
            anotherBean.sendGet();
            // System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
            // anotherBean.sendPost();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {
        String url = "https://xxx.xxx.com/xxxx/DownloadReport/2015/10/29/xxx/TransactionDetailReport.csv";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");

        String urlParameters = "username=xxxx&password=xxxx";

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        OutputStream wr = con.getOutputStream();
        // wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        // con.connect();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
        System.out
                .println("Content Encoding: " + con.getContentEncoding() + "\nContent Length: " + con.getContentLength()
                        + "\nContent Type: " + con.getContentType() + "\nContent: " + con.getContent());
    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {
        String url = "https://xxx.xxx.com/xxxx/DownloadReport/2015/10/29/xxx/TransactionDetailReport.csv";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");

        String urlParameters = "username=xxx&password=xxxx";
        // String urlParameters = "{" +
        // "\"username\":\"xxxx\",\"password\":\"xxxx\"" +
        // "}";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        // DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        OutputStream wr = con.getOutputStream();
        // wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        // con.connect();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        // BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new
        // InputStreamReader((InputStream) con.getContent()));
        // String theString = IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream(),
        // StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);
        // byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(con.getInputStream());
        // String theString = IOUtils.toString(byteArray);
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            // System.out.println(" " + inputLine);
        }

        /*
         * do { inputLine = inputReader.readLine(); response.append(inputLine +
         * "\n"); } while (inputLine != null);
         */

        // String finalResponse = new String(response, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        // inputReader.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
        // System.out.println("Response - theString: " + theString);
        // System.out.println("Response String: " + byteArray);
        System.out
                .println("Content Encoding: " + con.getContentEncoding() + "\nContent Length: " + con.getContentLength()
                        + "\nContent Type: " + con.getContentType() + "\nContent: " + con.getContent());
    }
}


**Response:**
***Sending 'GET' request to URL :*** "https://xxx.xxx.com/xxxx/DownloadReport/2015/10/29/xxx/TransactionDetailReport.csv";
***Response Code :*** 200
***Post parameters :*** username=xxxx&password=xxxx
***Response:*** ‹ •UmoÓ0þÞ_aR!©YÓn¬Í"¡2H›?ø„.ñ%1sâ`;[â¿syi×¦Í`NU;ñùîžçÎwþ‹wŸ—·ß¾\³Ôf2ø› ?FÃ·ÂJfžÇ\vƒú5»ÖZiÜì4RZ`QÚ ½rJ»oœvËØõF¬•ö{ûZ?¢»D«2çs–«™ÆÁ2i%%óè^×c±=÷g°]†Š¯;3Ð‰ÈçlòºXÑéÉ¬X-öb•[7†LÈõœ9ŸÊHp`4ä?»…Te0boµ ......
***Content Encoding:*** gzip
***Content Length:*** 761
***Content Type:*** text/html
***Content:*** sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@7c4ccb2f
```

I get the same response even with the POST method. Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong or what needs to be corrected.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
As per @Hendrik Simon's reponse, I can get the response in a readable format.
But now I face with another hurdle. The response now is

```
Response: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>    <title>500 - Server Error</title>    <meta charset="utf-8">    <style>        html {            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;        }        body {            margin: 17px 0 15px;            font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;            padding: 0;            text-align: center;            font-size: small;        }        #content {            display: block;            margin: 20px 14px 10px;            padding: 0 0 20px;            position: relative;        }        #container {            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;            border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);            text-align: left;            margin: 0 auto;            width: 640px;            min-height: 200px;        }        h2 {            font-size: 160%;            clear: left;            font-weight: 400;            margin: 0 0 5px;            text-align: left;        }        #content div {            color: #555555;            font-size: 95%;            line-height: 135%;        }        #logo {            background-color: #003C69;            background-image: none;            margin: 0;            min-height: 0;            padding: 0;            text-decoration: none;            text-indent: -9000px;        }        #logo a {            background-repeat: no-repeat;            background-image: url("cybersource_logo.gif");            height: 55px;            min-height: 0;            display: block;            overflow: hidden;        }    </style></head><body><div id="container">    <h1 id="logo"><a>CyberSource</a></h1>    <div id="content">        <h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.</h2>        <br/>        <div>If the problem persists please report your problem.</div>    </div></div><script src="ntpagetag.js"></script></body></html>
```

When I use the same URL on a browser or REST client I usually get a popup window to enter the credentials. On successfully submitting, I get the desired data. Can anyone guide me on how to handle this scenario using JAVA code?

Comment: Two things that stand out is that you are trying to send a request body in a GET request. The parameters in GET are supposed to be in the URL. And in the POST request, the content-type should probably *not* be text/plain, but this may depend on the particular service's definition. You should be sending a content-length, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response @RealSkeptic. Its working now as per Hendrik Simon's response. Can you help me further?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the response is gzip encoded and you do not unzip it.

Try removing the following line

```
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
```

**Update:**

As @RealSkeptic correctly mentioned you cannot write data to a connection if it is a `GET`-Request. With a GET-Request you have to add the parameters to the URL like this:

`http://...?param1=bla&param2=blubb`

I think, as soon as you call `con.setDoOutput(true);` your connection will automatically do a POST-Request, no matter what you set as request method. So you are never making a GET-Request in your example.

You can easily see that when you analyze your traffic with Wireshark for example.

As to the server error it's not easy to analyze that without reproducing it. And reqproducing it without knowing the URL is not possible, at least for me.

Comment: Tried removing that line. No luck. Still the same response.

Comment: Sorry, the response is in readable format now. My bad, I removed the line from the wrong place.

Comment: Someone please make this the right answer :D I spent a day before coming to this page. Remove "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" is the answer.